# Device depending neovim configuration

Tags: lua, neovim

I have a short question.

Currently, I am spending (way too much time) modding my neovim setup.
I have multiple devices where I use my setup and sync those with git (*second-best feature, after restoring my config every time I destroy everything*) but there are some small differences in my configuration like plugins, which I don't need on my on-the-way-notebook.

**Is there any way to differ in the lua configuration, on which device is currently running neovim?**

Sure, multi-branching would be a way, but I'd like a more comfortable way.
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use hostname to determine your device and use it to create configuration with conditions.

Lua code to get hostname :

```lua
local function get_hostname()
    local f = io.popen ("/bin/hostname")
    local hostname = f:read("*a") or ""
    f:close()
    hostname =string.gsub(hostname, "\n$", "")
    return hostname
end
```

Neovim configuration :

```lua
if get_hostname() == "foo" then
  do_something
else
  do_otherthing
end
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, that's exactly what I wanted :D